# GCM Push Notification - What ports do we need to open for outbound and inbound?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

For Google Push Notification,

1) All ports( 5228, 5229, 5230,443(both)) are outbound from mobile first server except 443 it is for both  and all  are TCP ports.

2) we need to open any ports for inbound.

when we try to send any type of push notification it is not reaching device, what is the issue may be.

Comment: By *Google Push Notification*, do you mean GCM?

Comment: Yes By Google Push Notification

Comment: Why haven't you opened 443 as well?

Comment: opened 443 also. i need to configure any thing in server.xml (IBM mobilefirst platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GCM notifications to work from IBM MobileFirst Server, ensure you have met the pre-requisites as detailed in the following:

1. [Set up guidelines](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/#setupAndroid)
2. [Setting up push notifications for Android](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_android.html)

To test if connectivity to GCM is proper and working, you can also try:

[Send a request from the command line for GCM to push a message](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07?hl=en)

You should also check with IT and network administrators to confirm that the ports are opened and connectivity verified. Another important point is that you should enable your firewall to allow connectivity to "https://android.googleapis.com/" and not whitelist individual IPs.

Comment: Thanks @Vivin.k i followed all those steps, still i have problem so i raised a question

Comment: Are there are any errors or exceptions in the logs when trying to send the notifications. If you are a BP or customer you can always raise a PMR